# Type Error: record() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'

Tags: python, typeerror, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have just started with python and i'm trying out new modules from random tutorials online.
I tried to write it exactly like the tutorial and even changing the name but it still keeps showing me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/Asjad/PycharmProjects/untitled/hello world.py", line 7, in <module>
   audio = r.record(j)
TypeError: record() missing 1 required positional argument: 'source'
```

I don't know how to go past this as this a new module and a new error with me

mainscript:

```
import speech_recognition as sy

file = ("D:\\Audio 1.wav")
r = sy.Recognizer # initialize the recognizer

with sy.AudioFile(file) as j:
    audio = r.record(j)

print('it contains', r.recognise_google(audio))
```

Comment: It seems the function `record()` uses an additional argument: `source`, with `record(j)` you're adding just one argument, when you should use two, from what I can tell

Comment: Try `r = sy.Recognizer()` with the parentheses.

Comment: Thank you everyone it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this line `r = sy.Recognizer`make an instance of Recognizer so you should do that instead `r = sy.Recognizer()`